# Accessing Class Function Isn't Outputting Data

Tags: c++

I've just started working on Classes and I'm unsure what my code is missing to produce the expected result. You enter song names and their duration into a vector and then my FOR loop should check if each songs duration is greater than 150. But it's not giving me any output. I'm assuming I'm not accessing the Song classes members incorrectly. I've highlighted the code I've written.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Song
{
public:
    void SetNameAndDuration(string songName, int songDuration)
    {
        name = songName;
        duration = songDuration;
    }
    void PrintSong() const
    {
        cout << name << " - " << duration << endl;
    }
    string GetName() const
    {
        return name;
    }
    int GetDuration() const
    {
        return duration;
    }

private:
    string name;
    int duration;
};

class Album
{
public:
    void SetName(string albumName)
    {
        name = albumName;
    }
    void InputSongs();
    void PrintName() const
    {
        cout << name << endl;
    }
    void PrintSongsLongerThan(int songDuration) const;

private:
    string name;
    vector<Song> albumSongs;
};

void Album::InputSongs()
{
    Song currSong;
    string currName;
    int currDuration;

    cin >> currName;
    while (currName != "quit")
    {
        cin >> currDuration;
        currSong.SetNameAndDuration(currName, currDuration);
        albumSongs.push_back(currSong);
        cin >> currName;
    }
}
// having trouble here:
void Album::PrintSongsLongerThan(int songDuration) const
{
    unsigned int i;
    Song currSong;

    cout << "Songs longer than " << songDuration << " seconds:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < albumSongs.size(); i++)
    {
        if (songDuration > 150)
        {
            currSong.PrintSong();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Album musicAlbum;
    string albumName;

    getline(cin, albumName);
    musicAlbum.SetName(albumName);
    musicAlbum.InputSongs();
    musicAlbum.PrintName();
    musicAlbum.PrintSongsLongerThan(150);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is an example of the input and what is expected for Output and what my Program is outputting.

[image]

Comment: With a rep of 57, you should already know that images are not to be posted.  Instead, post the code here (not on a link that could go down at any time).

Comment: Same goes with the input. I've dragged the code over, but I'm too damn lazy to retype the input.

Comment: Recommendation: Don't use a setter when a constructor could do the job better.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: Note: The parser will fail if given a song name that is longer than one word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues.

First off, if I understand the method correctly, the songDuration variable represents the duration that the songs have to be longer than in order to get printed. Therefore you should be passing in 150 to songDuration and not hard coding it in.

Second, you aren't setting the value of currSong to anything, so you aren't looking at the values of any of the songs. It is an unused and uninitialized variable.

What you're doing right now at this line:

`if (songDuration > 150)`

is pretty much just saying

`if (150 > 150)`

Since you're passing 150 into the songDuration variable, so nothing happens. Do you see the issue now?

What you want is :

```
if (albumSongs[i].GetDuration() > songDuration){
    // do print operation here
}
```